# Limits of integration in probability question

Tags: probability

I have a few questions in regard to the following example given  and corresponding solution in Wackerlys Mathematical Statistics;

Suppose $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ have jdf given by $f(y_{1},y_{2})=k(1-y_{2})$ if $0 \le y_{1} \le y_{2} \le 1.$ , $0$ elsewhere

Then it asks to find  (1) the value of k to make this valid, and (2) the marginals.

So I understand to find k we consider the double integral with the bounds given that makes sense to me. My confusion is in regard to the bounds considered when we are calculating the marginals. Why do we change from evaluating $dy_{2}$ from 0 to 1 to evaluating it from $y_{1}$ to $1?$ Furthermore, why didn't we couldn't we have these as its bound in the original double integral for finding k? It seems like those are bounds as well?

Below I will post the solutions that I am referring to;[image]

Comment: I suspect things may feel a lot easier if we use $X$ and $x$ instead of $Y_1$ and $y_1$, and $Y$ and $y$ instead of $Y_2$ and $y_2$. **Draw**  the region where the joint density function really "lives."  This is a **triangle** with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$.  To put it another way, it is the part of the unit square that is **above** the line $y=x$. Now the limits of integration should be clear.

Comment: Right I did do that and I do understand it. What I am mostly confused is why the limits change when calculating K compared to the marginals

Comment: When we compute $k$ we are doing a double integral over the triangle. When we for example compute $f_X(x)$ we are "integrating out" $y$, so we are computing a one variable integral. Note that to say in the triangle, $y$ goes from $y=x$ to $y=1$.  Similarly, when we integrate out $x$, it goes from $0$ to $y$.

Comment: Thanks, the part about integrating over the triangle makes sense. What is meant by integrating "out" one variable, etc?

Comment: To find the marginal of $X$, for any fixed value of $x$ we integrate the jdf with respect  to $y$, where $y$ ranges over its allowed values (which often, and in this case, depend on $x$).

Comment: AH I think I see, so I should look at its bounds in the definition of the jdf ?

Comment: In a sense the bounds are absolutely critical, for the shape of the jdf changes as you cross the bounds, in a dramatic way, from something non-zero to something $0$. For the first problem, if you had a triangular piece of metal of variable density, to find the mass of the metal you would integrate over the triangle, not over a square.